# returning info from a string

Tags: python, regex, string

`return poker_hand(list_of_five_cards)` returns a string similar to this:

```
**4-Diamonds/2-Clubs/5-Hearts/4-Spades/King-Spades (One pair.)
```

and I have created a string out of it I want the information inside the brackets. in this vein I have tried:

```
s = str(poker_hand(one_man))
print s
the_search = re.search(r"\((\w+)\)", s)
```

and this returns `None` when you type `print the_search`. I have also tried

```
s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(')')]
print s
```

which returns the whole string. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT sorry for the confusion I should be better,

input is `7-Spades/4-Clubs/3-Diamonds/3-Hearts/8-Spades (One pair.)`
desired output is `One pair`

re the assigning... trying to assign it now, will post the results

Comment: In your second snippet, you don't actually assign the result of the slice to anything.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of the **input** and desired **output**.

Comment: Really unclear. Try `re.findall(r'\(([^()]*)\)', s)`

Comment: If `print(s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(')')])` does not work, you need to make sure you have a string that contains `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 0):

the pattern you are using to find the item in brackets is not right.
you can try to test your regex in http://regexr.com/

```
import re
s = '**4-Diamonds/2-Clubs/5-Hearts/4-Spades/King-Spades (One pair.)'
pattern = r'\(.+\.\)'
for item in re.findall(pattern,s):
  print item.strip('().')


output:
One pair
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC at the end of your string you always have the closed brackets. Then try this:

```
'**4-Diamonds/2-Clubs/5-Hearts/4-Spades/King-Spades (One pair.)'.split('(')[1][:-1]
Out[1]: 'One pair.'
```

The idea is to split by the opening brackets, taking what's after, and deleting the closing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

> input is `7-Spades/4-Clubs/3-Diamonds/3-Hearts/8-Spades (One pair.)`
>   desired output is `One pair`

You can use something like:

```
import re
string = "7-Spades/4-Clubs/3-Diamonds/3-Hearts/8-Spades (One pair.)"
result = re.findall(r"\((.*?)\.?\)", string )
print result[0]
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/lphiPF)

---

Regex Explanation:

```
\((.*?)\.?\)

Match the character “(” literally «\(»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “.” literally «\.?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
Match the character “)” literally «\)»
```

Comment: thank yo very much for the explanation! this'll be something that I use indefinitely

Comment: Your welcome, if my answer helped you, please give it 1+ and mark it as the correct answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the groups:

```
    import re
    s = '**4-Diamonds/2-Clubs/5-Hearts/4-Spades/King-Spades (One pair.)'
    print (s)
    m = re.search(r'\(([\s\S]+)\.\)', s)
    print(m.group(1))
```